# Asp.net mvc elasticsearch full text search

Tags: asp.net-mvc, full-text-search

My search query does not work.
This is my program code

```
        var node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node);
        settings.DefaultIndex("HowToDo");
        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
        using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var instruction = db.Instructions.ToList();
            foreach (var i in instruction)
            {
                //client.IndexAsync<Instruction>(i, null);
                client.Index(i, idx => idx.Index(i.Id.ToString()));
            }
        }
```

Next I enter a word and I want to receive a list of instructions

```
var result = client.Search<Models.Classes_for_Db.Instruction>(s => s
               .From(0)
               .Take(10)
               .Query(qry => qry
                   .Bool(b => b
                       .Must(m => m
                           .QueryString(qs => qs
                               .DefaultField("_all")
                               .Query("10"))))));
        var list = result.Documents.ToList();
```

Comment: Define "does not work." Wrong results? No results? Doesn't compile? Something else? What should happen?

Comment: On the entered word, which occurs throughout the database, show a list of instructions in which the word is. An empty list is displayed.Maybe I'm writing incorrect instructions or an incorrect search request.